# Как получить значения аргументов конструктора в виде массива?

Tags: java

Есть метод:

```
public Food(boolean breakfast, boolean lunch, boolean dinner, boolean supper, boolean alcohol){
}
```

Как получить массив значений параметров метода `Food`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решается через java.reflection

Берем класс в котором содержится данный метод `food()`, допустим это `FoodClass`, тогда:

```
Method foodMethod=null;
Method[] declaredMethods = FoodClass.class.getDeclaredMethods(); //список всех методов
//если речь о конструкторе, то можно использовать class.getConstructors()
for (Method declaredMethod : declaredMethods) {
    if (declaredMethod.getName().equals("food")) {
            foodMethod=declaredMethod;
            break;
        }
    }
 //теперь в foodMethod у нас наш метод food
 TypeVariable<Method>[] types=foodMethod.getTypeParameters(); //получаем список параметров нашего метода 
 Class<?>[] classTypes=foodMethod.getParameterTypes(); //или такой список
```